# When are action helpers initialized?

Tags: zend-framework

I understand what action helpers do, but I can't figure out when they are initialized (an instance for each created). If I am not wrong, the _helper property of the controller contains a collection of instances for each helper class.

Am I right? If yes, are all helper actions(classes correspond to helper) initialized at bootstrap of Application(on each http request)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [this part of the ZF manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.broker), you will find a little more information on how action helpers work.

The `_helper` property does **not** hold a collection of helper instances, but holds an instance of 'Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker` which:-

> handles the details of registering helper objects and helper paths, as well as retrieving helpers on-demand.

Helpers are not instantiated in the bootstrap, but will be instantiated in the controller on demand when you use something like `$helper = $this->_helper->getHelper('helperName');` in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but what about some direct helper like, $this->_helper->url() ? Is it instantiated at the call ? And one more, if i override the hook methods, like pre-postDispatch, then to be called those methods, i have first to register this helper. So everytime i register a helper, it means that it is inistantiated too?

Comment: Regardless of how you call an action helper it is instantiated by the helperBroker when required, not before.